# Enumerate every row, excluding the first one in a table

Tags: tables, counters

I want to numerate every row, excluding the first one, in a tabularx environment. In my MWE the first line, headline, is also numerated. How can I turn this off?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\stepcounter{rowcount}\therowcount.\hspace*{1pt}}X|X}
head1 & head2\\
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text & txet\\
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text & txet\\
text & txet\\
text & txet\\
text & txet\\
text & txet\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one option, using a conditional for printing the value in each row:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\let\oldtabularx\tabularx
\renewcommand{\tabularx}{\setcounter{rowcount}{-1}\oldtabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{\stepcounter{rowcount}\ifnum\value{rowcount}=0\else\therowcount.\hspace*{1pt}\fi}X|
  X}
  \bfseries head1 & \bfseries head2 \\
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text & textt \\
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text & text \\
  text & text \\
  text & text \\
  text & text \\
  text & text
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

`rowcount` is started from `-1` at the beginning of *every* `tabularx`, making the header be at `\value{rowcount}=0`. So, we only print `\therowcount.` when not `\value{rowcount}=0`, or

```
\ifnum\value{rowcount}=0\else\therowcount.\hspace*{1pt}\fi
```